# set zoomfactor in phantomjs + Selenium webdriver using JAVA

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using PhantomJS with selenium webdriver. When the browser is invoked then it is invoked in too much zoom level. I want to reduce the zoom percent of the browser window.
So please tell me the appropridate answer to perform this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String zoomJs= "document.body.style.transform='scale(1.0)';";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(zoomJs);
```

Comment: I found one another solution that is: driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1936, 1056));

Comment: @Mayank, glad the solution helped. Please accept it as solution, if it  worked for you. For the another solution `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1936, 1056));` you are basically restricting it to your computer's screen resolution. It may pose problems when you run it in another computer.